# reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response

Tags: spring, rest, project-reactor, rest-client

I have spring reactive a micro-service which call another micro-service to get list of products, but it keep failing with the error

```
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxLift] :
```

This is how i get `WebClient` object

```
public WebClient createWebClient(HttpRequestConfig config, String baseUri) {
    Builder clientBuilder = webClientBuilder(config)
             .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.newConnection().compress(true)))
            .baseUrl(baseUri);
    return clientBuilder.build();
}
```

Any idea about the issue?

Comment: Can you provide you 'get list of products' code logic?